# Authentication flow for Angular application for users in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an Angular application which talks to several WEB API's to provide an interacted UI. I am finding really hard time in finding a way to. I am following  this [article](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/02/28/using-openidconnect-with-azure-ad-angular5-and-webapi-core-angular5-configuration/) which explains the Angular part of it. I am able to get the token at client side. How can my dot net core web API validate the token if the client sends this id token?

Comment: In it's document : http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/02/28/using-openidconnect-with-azure-ad-angular5-and-webapi-core-webapi-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JwtBearer middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/) which enables an application to receive an OpenID Connect bearer token. In [this document](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/02/28/using-openidconnect-with-azure-ad-angular5-and-webapi-core-webapi-configuration/) it provides code sample .

Or you can use [AzureADAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.AddAzureADBearer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.azureadauthenticationbuilderextensions.addazureadbearer?view=aspnetcore-2.2) Method in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` library :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

And bind the config in `appsettings.json`:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "cb1c3f2e-a2dd-xxxx-bf8f-f75ab18b21ac",
    "ClientId": "511ece54-a7a2-xxxx-a9f9-bd224e1d0a0f"
},
```