# How to get AD access token and pass it to web api controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, access-token, owin-middleware

How to get AD access token from login.microsoftonline.com and pass access token to web api controller?
as I need "access token" as such to pass on to another partner company website url  via post request.

Below code doing AAD authentication as expected but also I need "access token" as such,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";


            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
        });

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Comment: According to my understanding, you need the AD access token to call the API protected by AD then your API will call another application protected by AD. Is that right? Besides, could you please tell me your api application and partner company website are in the different tenant?

Comment: Yes, my api application and partner company website are in the different tenant. My API will call another partner company application protected by inhouse-custom Authentication provider NOT AAD. Partner company application will verify the signature segment of AAD access token (provided by my app) to validate the authenticity of the token so that the token can be trusted by partner company app to proceed further.

Comment: Since you just use Azure AD to project your web API, I think you should validate token in api application. why do you use company application to validate token.

Comment: Scenario is bit difficult to explain. Can we have chat?

Comment: Sorry. I cannot have chat.

Comment: @JimXu, we as a vendor providing IAM service (like AAD) to our clients/partners which issues access token, which will be consumed by all our client/partners side applications. In order to issue access token, client app has to supply us password/clientcredentials/AADToken to prove its identity, if they supply AADToken then we need to validate the authenticity of the token so that the token can be trusted by our app to proceed further to issue access token & complete the call. The question is how to validate the authenticity of the AAD access tokens using c#?

Comment: If you want to know how to validate AAD token with C#, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840170/validating-the-token-recieved-from-azure-ad-b2c-using-the-values-from-jwks-uri/59851523#59851523

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210647/discussion-between-191180rk-and-jim-xu).

Comment: Above code snippet attached in the original post, not exposing access token but internally it manage to get access token & validating, how to do it more transparent way? where I get access token & validate it using custom code for better understanding.

Comment: If you want to get Azure AD access token, you can use Microosft SDK `msal`. There are some [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) you can refer to

Answer (score 0):

> Above code snippet attached in the original post, not exposing access token but internally it manage to get access token & validating, how to do it more transparent way?

You can get tokens after authentication  :

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";         // Microsoft identity platform
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants (here simplified)
});
```

And get tokes in controller :

```
var idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

But with your code snippets it won't return access token since you are implement the sign-in process , not token request . You shall use  ADAL/MSAL to get access token for accessing the protected APIs . See code samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2) .

> where I get access token & validate it using custom code for better understanding.

You can understand the validation of token signature from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57848985/5751404) .

Comment: Thanks for your understanding & solution. Now I can able to get token in controller/action which is decorated with [Authorize] & validated the token using AAD public keys, validation success which solves my problem. But your above statement "your code snippets it won't return access token since you are implement the sign-in process , not token request" which contradicts the real time behavior of my above code. Please clarify or let me if have missed anything to consider.

Comment: Your OIDC config which by default is OIDC sign in flow which grant type is id_token , you   should use authorization code flow which grant type is code to get access token : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: [Authorize] attribute on top of controller, wont complain if id_token is supplied instead of access token? any c# sample to get access token via authorization code flow in transparent manner? any possibility to get access token after end user get authenticated via FIDO2 flow?

Comment: [Authorize] will check user's identity , that is related to id_token since claims from id_token will fill user's principle  , HOw do you want to get the token ? check the code sample from above comment .

Comment: How do you want to get the token?  I want get token from AAD after FIDO authentication (or) after username&password verification. Also inside the controller I need a copy of that AAD access token for some business need. Thats it! the above provided code sample is not in user friendly manner.

Comment: Check code sample : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/Client/Startup.cs#L57 . Use MSAL to get the token and save to cache which could be retired in controller .

Answer (score 0):

Hi please download and follow the instructions provided in the sample. It helps you set up a Web APi first and provides a client application that first signs in a user and then obtains an Access Token for a web Api

[How to secure a Web API built with ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/README.md)

Once you can get the sample to work, you can replace the sample's Web Api with your partner's Web Api.