# Azure easy auth get user role based on AD user Id ASP.net core app WebAPI

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, easy-auth

I'm following [link](https://intellitect.com/authenticate-without-code/) to make authentication and authorization.

I able to create successfully token based on [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantID%7D/oauth2/token)

After that I calling GET API using sayhello. It's everything fine, but I want based on token and UserId/Password of AD user get user role.
I search a lot but not getting any concrete solution.

Comment: Did you mean that you wanna analyze the token to get the user information(user id, user role, etc.) and then according to the role to make the request bypass or block?

Comment: How I decode token?

Comment: trying to find a jwt token decode library, here's the online decode tool. https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 1):

To decode the Azure Active Directory JWT token using the tool, you can use this online decode tool [JSON Web Tokens - jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

Here is an example covered of how to verify and decode Azure Active Directory Token, refer this [article](https://liangjunjiang.medium.com/verify-and-decode-azure-activity-directory-token-bc72cf7010bc).

If you want to manually decode a bearer token using azure active directory, you can use `JwtBearer` or `AddAzureADBearer` middleware to validate the access token.

Please refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830076/manual-decode-a-bearer-token-using-azure-active-directory-how-do-i-validate) which contains code to decode a bearer token.