# how to retrieve tenant id from bearer token in azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to retrieve tenant id from bearer token to pass on to next web call in Azure Data Factory. I can see the required information in the jwt.io website when passed the bearer token. Is it possible to achieve this using ADF?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without writing your own Azure Function which decodes the token like this it may be a challenge. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57848985/5070440 or depending on the grants the token has you might be able to call a REST API to list the tenants it has access to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list?tabs=HTTP