# AspCore 2.2 Azure Active Directory : Authorization failed

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I try to integrate Azure Active Directory and Asp.net CORE 2.2.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

**Appsettings.json**

```
{"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "xxxxxx", 
"ClientId": "xxxx" } },"AllowedHosts": "*"}
```

The results:
**Error : info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.**

Please, i found any solution for this issue.

Thank you very much

Comment: Take a look this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45807822/3613462

Comment: I dont know if this is your case, but if you are trying to authenticate with a token for MS Graph, it wont work. You need to issue a token for your own Web API and not reuse tokens from other resources.

Answer (score 0):

May be a good solution is to modify the startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

And includes in the controller

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AzureAD")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddAzureADBearer` adds JWT Bearer authentication to your app for Azure Active Directory Applications. It is usually used by protecting your application with AAD tokens . If that is you scenario , check the detailed error message of Authorization failed. You can refer to below link for code samples :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57619013/5751404

Another scenario is you want to add Azure AD login authentication .The simplest way is to use the default Azure AD template : `Change Authentication` --> `Work or School Accounts`  . Or manually add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` package and use `AddAzureAD` extension:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54546245/5751404

Comment: I try your simplest way but it doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: show the details , not just `doesn't work ` , what is the scenario and what is the error message

Comment: Ok i generated the solution from Visual Studio 2019. > Work Account > My tenant was here but when i compile the code, the authentication doesn't work. So may be in the VS Template they're missing something...

Comment: The authentication is failed. By default the controller uses [Authorize]. In my case, i change [Authorize] by [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AzureAD")] and it works ! :)